# Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection when running fromJSON in r

Tags: r, shiny

i have been trying to run this code.

```
url<- paste0("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=",
          dataIwant$latitude[i],"&lon=",dataIwant$longitude[i],
            "&cnt=39&appid=")

req <- fromJSON(paste0(url,key))
```

i have been trying to run this code.the url is a valid one. after running the second one this error keeps coming

```
   Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

can anyone help?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/owmr/README.html

Comment: thanks for ur help